# copy va_list parameters to pass to another task

Tags: embedded, printf, variadic, variadic-functions

I am in a multithreading embedded environment (FreeRTOS).
I need a function like `printf`, with variadic argumets that instead of output characters, should pack format string and all parameters in an array of byte, and then I have to pass that array to another process that should create va_list object from this array and pass it to `vprintf`
Is it possible, and how?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't just write the formatted output characters to an "array of byte" and pass that array to the other process? If you really want to call vprintf (instead of plain old printf), then you could write a small variadic wrapper.

Comment: @Pinetwig more than one task needs to print (output to uart) some messages, logs and traces. But it would be better to create a process that do the "dirty work", it can have a large stack. The others task would call a variadic function to "transmit" in some way (Queue for example) the format string and the parameters. Otherwise all process canning printf wound have a large stack, and wound consume a lot of CPU